# a promised sign

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of " a promised sign" in the below paragraph? 
Can we paraphrase it as an expected miracle?

"I am waiting for an arrival, a return, a promised sign. This can be futile, or immensely pathetic: in Erwartung (Waiting), a woman waits for her lover, at night, in the forest; I am waiting for no more than a telephone call, but the anxiety is the same. Everything is solemn: I have no sense of proportions." by Roland Barthes.

Comment: The wording of your text is a little "odd", in that apparently no "sign" has "promised".  I would say that the writer slightly abused the metaphor.

Comment: @HotLicks ... and apparently had just made a bulk purchase of assorted punctuation marks while they were on sale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my bible classes in school 'the promised sign' was a rainbow that God put over the earth as a symbol, to Noah the he would never flood the earth again. 
https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis+9&version=CEV

Another possibility is that 'the promised sign' refers to the star that heralded the birth of Jesus.

The writer is talking about the unreasonable level of intensity he feels, on waiting for his lover, and I think is wittily comparing himself to Noah waiting for the rainbow - so he can feel safe, so he can feel - relief!

He is saying that waiting for a sign from his lover feels as important to him, as seeing the rainbow would be, to Noah.

So it's quite humourous, and wry - he is kind of poking fun at himself and also asking 'why is it like this'? Why do I feel this so intensely?

He is using 'promised sign' to denote the enormous importance that he places on receiving 'a sign' - a response - from his beloved.

You could paraphrase 'promised sign' here as 'an expected miracle'. It would mean pretty much the same. But in that case, I would imagine an angel descending to grant his wish, rather than imagining him following or hoping for, a star or rainbow.

It would still be quite funny.